# hello! there is someone who can help me on my project? this is my code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

```
Public Class frmColor
    Dim red, green, yellow, blue, orange As New frmChanger

    Private Sub BtnRed_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRed.Click
        frmChanger.Show(red)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnGreen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGreen.Click
        frmChanger.Show(green)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnYellow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnYellow.Click
        frmChanger.Show(yellow)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnBlue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBlue.Click
        frmChanger.Show(blue)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnOrange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnOrange.Click
        frmChanger.Show(orange)
    End Sub

End Class
```

that is my code on form1....

```
Public Class frmChanger
    Private Sub PnlRed_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PnlRed.Paint
        PnlRed.BackColor = Color.Red
    End Sub

    Private Sub PnlGreen_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PnlGreen.Paint
        PnlGreen.BackColor = Color.Green
    End Sub

    Private Sub PnlYellow_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PnlYellow.Paint
        PnlYellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    End Sub

    Private Sub PnlBlue_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PnlBlue.Paint
        PnlBlue.BackColor = Color.Blue
    End Sub

    Private Sub PnlOrange_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PnlOrange.Paint
        PnlOrange.BackColor = Color.Orange
    End Sub
End Class
```

and this is my code on form2....

what i need is, when i clicked the btnRed on form1, on form2 only the PnlRed show..
when the BtnGreen is clicked, Pnlgreen on form2..

my problem is both panel colors show when i click only one button.. what should i do? can someone help me please.

Comment: Please try and let us know what didn't work, I hope you were not expecting someone to do your job :)

Comment: it didnt work..i tried to put other color but all panel became red..even i click other button

Comment: im sorry,what i mean is, when i click the button red, all panel in form 2 become red. if i click the green button all panel in form2 became green..what i want is only  one panel change the color.

Comment: This code sounds like VBA not VB.Net isn't is ?
Instead of `frmChanger.Show(yellow)` why not saying `yellow.Visible`
If VB.Net, Why not simply setting the background color of panels in the `frmChanger` constructor `New()` ? Using the `paint event` is not a good practice in your context. In the button click event.

Comment: I think you need to read the VBA https://excelerator.solutions/2017/12/04/getting-started-vba-userforms/  about UserForms or VB.Net https://riptutorial.com/winforms  about WinForms

Answer (score 0):

Add a Form level variable to `frmChanger` with its datatype as `Color` and its scope as `Friend` (so it can be seen from `frmColor`). This code is using the default instance of the form. You don't really need a separate form for each color. You only want to have a different color shown. How about a single panel that will have different colors instead of multiple panels.

In the `Form1` code (your `frmColor`)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.panelColor = Color.Red
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
```

Repeat for the other buttons with `= Color.Green` etc.

In `Form2` (your `frmChanger`)

```
Friend panelColor As Color

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Panel1.BackColor = panelColor
End Sub
```

Comment: it didnt work..i tried to put other color but all panel became red..even i click other button

Comment: im sorry,what i mean is, when i click the button red, all panel in form 2 become red. if i click the green button all panel in form2 became green..what i want is only one panel change the color.

Comment: im sorry,what i mean is, when i click the button red, all panel in form 2 become red. if i click the green button all panel in form2 became green..what i want is only one panel change the color.

Comment: @RachelleBugarin I used `Panel1` to demonstrate. Use the name of panel your want to change in the `Form2.Load`.

Comment: @RachelleBugarin In reply to your first comment above. Say "other button" is the green button. Then the code in the other button would be. `Form2.panelColor = Color.Green`
    `Form2.Show()`